# React Native .apk crash at launch but work on emulator

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, apk

Since my last update, my build .apk app is not working anymore on Android. On emulator, the app is working properly but when i open it on phone, it's crash instantly.

package.json :

```
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.9.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "expo": "~46.0.13",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "^0.14.6",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

app.json :

```
  "expo": {
    "name": "name",
    "slug": "name",
    "version": "0.9.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./src/assets/icon_android.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./src/assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#fff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./src/assets/icon_android.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "xx.xxx.xx"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./src/assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "myid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you to everyone who will help me! from what i could see on similar problems, it could come from the packages

Comment: You should check `adb logcat` for getting the exact error message and may be also a stack trace of the problem.

Comment: thank you, I thought about it but unfortunately I did not find any filter allowing to sort the logs well, I found myself with 40 pages in a few seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up starting from an old save which allowed me to isolate the problem:

it seems that the expo-updates package crashes the app if present in package.json